# Invoking the scala action from java to write unit testing case

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, testng

I am working on the play framework project. I have the scala project developed. Now, my requirement is i wanna to write the unit testing class using testng or junit. I could write the unit testing class and can compile, run.

The problem now i am facing is i couldn't invoke the scala controller action.I am using play-2.2.* version and scala IDE.

Here is the code i tried to invoke the scala action into java method.

```
@Test
private void testHandShake(){

  Result result callAction(controllers.library.routes.ref.Assets.handshake, 
       new FakeRequest(GET,"/library/assets/handshake"));

   System.out.println("Result::"+result);
}
```

Could anyone help me how to call the scala action to return the result.

TIA..,

Comment: If I am not wrong... then you can not use Scala code in Java code.

Comment: @Sarvesh I seen some examples by googling. It's possible to mix both java and scala.

Comment: Its possible to use Java libs ( or code ) in Scala... but I don't think the other way is doable. You can make sure by doing a helloworld :) .

Comment: @Sarvesh I could compile and run the test class created against the scala action. Now, i am stucked with calling the underlying methods associated with the scala actions.

Comment: And what's the error? Besides the code looking not compilable.

Comment: @MariusSoutier I am getting the error lilke "This is not a Java application and it cannot be invoked in this way. I can assume it's because of i used the HandlerRef. My question is how to call the scala action using methods that associated with the scala actions